# cannot install intamap package in R ubuntu 12.04 (java concerned)

Tags: java, r, ubuntu, installation, package

I am very new to Ubuntu, currently running 12.04, I would like to install `intamapInteractive` package in `R` .
I can install it normally through the install packages in R-studio as I have always done, but when I run

```
library (intamapInteractive)
```

this message is returned:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘intamapInteractive’
```

I have read and tried but I am still very far from a solution.

My R version is

```
irene@saltafossi:~$ R --version
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

and my java, that I have installed today probably wrongly is:

```
irene@saltafossi:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
irene@saltafossi:~$
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this solve the problem: `sudo R CMD javareconf`?

Comment: no it didn't I tried that before, but Paul's answer solves the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for the error message you got lead me to [the following link](http://stdioe.blogspot.nl/2012/08/libjvmso-cannot-open-shared-object-file.html). The problem is that the location of java related .so files changes between updates of ubuntu. The solution proposed in the link is to change your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the location where the needed .so files are located. The following quote from the blog post provides more details:

> The location of JDK is always changed because of updates but Ubuntu
>   stores the links of current JVM in default-java directory. It is
>   /usr/lib/jvm/default-java in my Linux. Two directories must be added
>   to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The first one is jre/lib/i386 and the second one
>   is jre/lib/i386/client or jre/lib/i386/server in default-java
>   directory. Use of export solves my problem.

Comment: Works now. I swear I tried that way before, because I found it in stackoverflow, but it didn't work, no idea what I did wrong, well it works now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Great that Pauls solution worked for you! For other people who might find this thread, we solved the rJava installation-issue on our servers (Red Hat) by changing from openjdk to sun-jdk.